# Unable to do conversion of datatype in U-sql

Tags: u-sql

I am facing issue doing some transformations using U-sql one of the issue is while changing the Date format, Only when I skip the First rows(1) I am able to convert the date format. But I do need the column names so I cannot Skip the first row. Also I need to do some other transformations like data type conversion and simple concatenations.Below is my sample code.Kindly help.

```
DECLARE @dir string = "/storefolder/Sourcefile/dwfile3.csv";
DECLARE @file_set_path string = "/BCBSvermot/Sample_output.csv";


@data = 
    EXTRACT 
            CHECK_DATE string,

    FROM @dir
    USING Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows:1);

@result = SELECT 
Convert.ToDateTime(CHECK_DATE).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") AS CHECK_DATE
FROM @data;

OUTPUT @result
TO @file_set_path
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

Thanks,
Rav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a function similar to this:

```
DECLARE @func Func<string,string> = 
    (s) =>{
           DateTime i; 
           var x = DateTime.TryParse(s, out i); 
           return x?((DateTime)i).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) : s;
          };
```

Then you can use it on your queries

```
@result = 
SELECT @func(CHECK_DATE) AS CHECK_DATE
FROM @data;
```

Comment: Thanks Jorge, I tried your Function but came across an error                                                          
Resolution
Make sure that a valid C# expression is specified.
Description
C# compiler reported that this expression is not valid C#.
Details
at token '(', line 9
near the ###:
**************
mple_output.csv";
DECLARE @func Func<string,string> = 
    (s) =>{
           DateTime i; 
           var x = DateTime.TryParse(s, out i); 
           return x? ### ((DateTime?)i).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") : s;
          };